# When exporting the report to Excel, the default xls file is limited to 64k rows

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I have created a c# winforms application that has a reportviewer.  When exporting the report to Excel, the default xls file is limited to 64k rows.  I have searched and found that changing the rendering to EXCELOPENXML will solve the problem, however when I inspect the array rendering extentions:

```
RenderingExtension[] re = reportViewer1.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions();
```

There are only 3, Excel, PDF and Word.

Without upgrading the application to vs2012? What do I have to do to get the export option to render an Excel 2007/10 format without the 64k row limit?

Comment: You can't.  The 64K row limit is internal to older versions of Excel.  If you just want to output without a row limit for those who can actually read it, use CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

you just need the  [PIA office interop dlls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) you don't need VS 2012. The Office 2007 Dlls first came with Visual Studio 2008. These are the earliest ones to support the new larger format.

You can download the [Office 2010 PIA DLLs here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)

Comment: Thank you, but how do I add the rendering option to the report writer? Looking through the object browser I see the reportwriter has a sealed class RenderingExtention.  Can I add it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com) for manipulate with Excel-files. This is a free library that does not need MS Office installed to work with it's file.